# captive portal / walled garden on pop up window on android not appearing

Tags: domain-name-system, rewrite

I don't normally ask for help, but i've been stuck on this for a couple of days - and any pointers anyone may have will be very much appreciated.

I have created a wifi hotspot (captive portal / walled garden) - using Windows Server 2012, Unbound DNS and an Apple Extreme router. I have IIS running which is taking care of redirects using the URL re-writer and all is good for iOS devices.

I am trying to get android devices to display the pop-up CNA window when they join the wifi network. I'm doing this by this rule in my web.config

```
            <rule name="android rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="(.*)generate_204(.*)" />
                <!-- <action type="Redirect" url="http://supplierfinder.ubm-com.net/WebPage.cshtml" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" /> -->
                <action type="Rewrite" url="WebPage.cshtml" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

I am sure this redirect is working, and serving out the page when the device connects to the network. Here is a log entry

2015-09-05 19:06:48 W3SVC2 WIN-8CHVURO21ID 10.0.1.2 GET /generate_204 - 80 - 10.0.1.12 HTTP/1.1 Dalvik/1.6.0+(Linux;+U;+Android+4.4.2;+GT-N7100+Build/KOT49H) - - clients3.google.com 200 0 0 4143

as you can see - I get the android http://client32.google.com/generate_204 request coming in - and I'm responding with a URL Rewrite to a valid page (which is being served) 200. What I would expect to happen is the Android Device would then perform the request again - and then open a browser up and display the page. This doesn't happen.

I've reviewed the android source code for walled garden connections, and as far as I can see what I'm returning looks valid.. (below is the source code from the Android OS - note the 204 logic).

```
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(WALLED_GARDEN_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS);
         urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
         urlConnection.getInputStream();
         // We got a valid response, but not from the real google

         return urlConnection.getResponseCode() != 204;
     } catch (IOException e) {
         if (DBG) {
             log("Walled garden check - probably not a portal: exception " + e);
         }

         return false;

     } finally {
         if (urlConnection != null) {

             urlConnection.disconnect();
         }
     }
```

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Set up is

Windows Server 2012 - using Unbound DNS,
IIS 8.5 with URL Rewrite extensions (http on port 80 enabled)
DHCP server on the Airport Extreme router (as I can't disable it)

My DNS looks like this

interface: 0.0.0.0

access-control: 10.0.0.0/8 allow

```
local-zone: "." redirect
local-data: ". A 10.0.1.2"
```

I'm stuck at the moment - searching for a fix in google has been a little bit fruitless as everyone does captive portals with 3rd party products - am starting to think I should have taken that approach also :)

Thanks for reading... cheers

Steve